# Eclipse "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified" (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to add my Tomcat server to Eclipse but I get the message "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified." I've attached a screenshot to show what values I'm entering:

[image]

Notice that Finish button is disabled so I can't continue.The installation directory I've entered here is the same directory as CATALINA_HOME (in tomcat.service). To add the server to Ubuntu prior, I followed this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

I can also confirm that when I start Tomcat, and open http://localhost:8080 in my browser that Tomcat is running and it's version is Apache Tomcat/8.5.35. So Tomcat is working OK it seems.

Anything I'm doing wrong in Eclipse?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? Why does no one ever mention that?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem until I enabled +rwx permissions for the entire Tomcat installation directory.

From the directory one level up from where Tomcat is installed, enter in the terminal:

> sudo chmod -R 755 apache-tomcat-version

Restart Eclipse and your Server setup Finish button should now be activated.

Comment: It worked for me after restart the computer. Thanks!
I was some weeks with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this on Windows 10 as I did, you should click on the Browse button in the Tomcat installer and go into the Tomcat folder. windows will ask for permission and then everything will be okay after that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the tar file, unzipped it to my ~/Downloads directory. When I use this path, it doesn't give an error. I guess permissions as the /opt/tomcat directory is owned by tomcat user(?) Anyway, that seems to have got me pass that issue, I've yet to write an app and run it in Eclipse to test it all out.

Comment: This is actually how you're supposed to do it, using something that's *not* your production setup.